# Can I access custom html tag <component> or <slot> contents

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element

Let's say I want to create a custom html element such as:

```
<video-container>
  <video></video>
</video-container>
```

So I create a template like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   etc..
   <content></content>
</div>
```

Then I attach it to the page via an HTML Element Prototype `createdCallback`.

Inside that callback I want to be able to attach listeners to the `video` element so I can do stuff on `play`, `pause` etc.. It's not clear to me if there is anyway to access the video tag passed in. I can get access to the `content` tag but it doesn't show any child nodes. Is this possible?

I can access the video element if I just grab the whole document and get the video element but this is ugly because I want to be able to get only the video tag in the scope of the present custom element.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Direct way**

You should access it by using `querySelector` on the custom element itself:

```
VideoContainerPrototype.createdCallback = function ()
{
    var video1 = this.querySelector( 'video' ) 
}
```

You don't need to pass by the Shadow DOM.

---

**Shadow way**

But if you want to get it from the Shadow root you can use the [`assignedNodes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/assignedNodes) method on your `<slot>` element (formerly `getDistributedNodes()` on `<content>`):

```
var video2 = this.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'slot' ).assignedNodes()[1]
```

It returns an Array of *Nodes* that were inserted. Because in your example there's a text Node at index `[0]` you'll have to get the Node at `[1]`.

*Note:* You can also use named slots if you want to get your `<video>` element at index [0].